# Changing a two page view in to a single page AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are currently having a two page application where the users will enter the data and those is passed to the database and the results are displayed in a grid in the next page

```
<div class="md-padding col-md-6">
    <div class="row form-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
               href="Views/Angular/results.html"
               ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">
           Submit
       </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The results.html has the grid that shows the result. Instead of navigating to the next page how can I shows the result grid on the same page

Answer (score 0):

by using ng-show directive  for example.....

result.html

```
<div ng-show="page.result">
   <h1> this is result page </h1>
</div>
```

user.html

```
<div ng-show="page.user">
   <h1> this is user page </h1>
<div>
```

> by default show user.html when page is loading set `page.user = true`
>   set on controller
>
> after submit user data set `page.user = false` and `page.result = true` to
>   show in page

for more detail [click here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ng-hide-and-ng-show-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't do two components and call them via selector at one page? In the second component you set the content after you clicked the button and will pop up immediately your data